# how to get second last record from driverid Sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have following below i have three records in DriverID "134"  i want second last data how do this anyone help me how to get Second last data
AND
can you please help me how to fatch data from my table sort every second last record more then one driverid
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Row_Number()` Window function

```
With cte as
(
select *,Row_Number()over(order by Transdate desc) as Rn from yourtable 
Where DriverID = 134
)
Select * 
from cte 
Where Rn = 2
```

To handle when there is only one record for the give `DriverID` then use this

```
With cte as
(
select *,Row_Number()over(order by Transdate desc) as Rn,
count(1)over() as cnt from yourtable 
Where DriverID = 134
)
Select * 
from cte 
Where (Rn = 2 and cnt > 1) or (Rn = 1 and cnt = 1)
```

**Note:** If there is a tie in last second record and you want both the records then use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`

**Update :**

To find the second last record for **all** `DriverID's` add Partition by in `Row_number` and remove the `DriverID` from `Where` clause

```
With cte as
(
select *,Row_Number()over(Partition by DriverID order by Transdate desc) as Rn,
count(1)over(Partition by DriverID) as cnt from yourtable 
)
Select * 
from cte 
Where (Rn = 2 and cnt > 1) or (Rn = 1 and cnt = 1)
```

Comment: You were faster than me... +1 But: you might use <=2 to catch cases where there is only one record... (depends on the real-world needs of course).

Comment: @Shnugo - Yeah, you are right. Updated the answer accordingly. We cannot use <=2 because it will pull two records when you have more than 1 record for given `DriverID`

Comment: can you please help me how to fatch data  from my table sort every second last record more then one driverid

Comment: @AddiKhan - check the last query

Comment: THANKS Dear :) Boss:)

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY key DEC) AS rownumber,
 columns
 FROM tablename
 ) AS foo
 WHERE rownumber <= 2
```